# gmail imap bad unknown command in java

Tags: java, email, sockets, gmail, imap

i'm trying to access my gmail inbox with java by using socket (not java mail api).
i succesfully establish the  connection but select inbox command is not recognized. here is my code. and the output i get.

```
    SSLSocketFactory sslsocketfactory = HttpsURLConnection.getDefaultSSLSocketFactory();
    SSLSocket sslsocket = (SSLSocket) sslsocketfactory.createSocket("imap.gmail.com", 993);

    BufferedReader sin = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(sslsocket.getInputStream()));
    PrintWriter output = new PrintWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(sslsocket.getOutputStream()));

String line;
 output.println("A004 LOGIN my-mail-here my-pass-here");
    output.println("A005 SELECT [GMAIL]/myinbox");
    output.println("A006 LOGOUT");
    output.flush();
    while ((line = sin.readLine()) != null)
    System.out.println(line);
```

and here is the output i get :

```
* OK Gimap ready for requests from 78.185.154.27 o19if1214052bkq.44
A005 BAD Unknown command o19if1214052bkq.44
* CAPABILITY IMAP4rev1 UNSELECT IDLE NAMESPACE QUOTA ID XLIST CHILDREN X-GM-EXT-1 UIDPLUS COMPRESS=DEFLATE
A004 OK my-mail@gmail.com my-name my-surname authenticated (Success)
```

what may be the problem? login works but select doesn't work. i tried starttls , it also doesn't work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

<strike>Because you're doing it wrong :)</strike>

```
005 SELECT myinbox
```

will do what you are trying to do.

A great way to test out these sorts of things is with openssl

> openssl s_client -crlf -connect imap.gmail.com:993

here's an example using my gmail account. My Drafts is listed as:

> * LIST (\HasChildren \HasNoChildren) "/" "[Gmail]/Drafts"

```
003 select Drafts
* FLAGS (\Answered \Flagged \Draft \Deleted \Seen $MDNSent Junk $Forwarded NonJunk)
* OK [PERMANENTFLAGS (\Answered \Flagged \Draft \Deleted \Seen $MDNSent Junk $Forwarded NonJunk \*)] Flags permitted.
* OK [UIDVALIDITY 620224742] UIDs valid.
* 0 EXISTS
* 0 RECENT
* OK [UIDNEXT 25] Predicted next UID.
003 OK [READ-WRITE] Drafts selected. (Success)
```

That being said, what I think is happening is that the imap server is async, and you're not waiting for it to authenticate you before sending the select command - that's why the error is coming back before the login result in your output

Comment: Actually ... you know what I think is happening; the imap server is async, and you're not waiting for it to authenticate you before sending the `select` command - that's why the error is coming back before the login result in your output. Again, you can test your actual commands by connecting to the imap server directly.

Comment: as you said i donwloaded openssl and connected with the parameters you gave to me. i can connect my account but again after login command, select command gives me a bad command error

Comment: here is what i type and what i get 
ME:openssl s_client -crlf -connect imap.gmail.com:993
SERVER: lots of stuf here and at end OK Gimap ready for requests from my ip here
ME:A001 LOGIN my-email my-pass
SERVER:BAD INVALID TAG o23123123bkg.1
CAPABILITY IMAP4rev1 UNSELECT IDLE NAMESPACE QUOTA ID XLIST CHILDREN X-GM-EXT-1 UIDPLUS COMPRESS=DEFLATE
ADD01 OK my-email-here my-name my-surname authenticated(success)
ME:A002 SELECT Inbox
server: BAD Couldnt parse command

Comment: OK the thing was async imap server. thread.sleep(2000) just worked fine after logining my account